# Shopify version control for teams?

Tags: version-control, shopify

I'm trying to figure out a solution to effective source control for our customized Shopify store. I work on a team with 4 other developers and I'm hoping someone might have some advice on how to implement some form of source control so we can roll it back if needed and so we don't step on each others toes. Any advice would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: this? https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/using-themes/managing-themes/duplicating-themes

Answer (score 0):

Use the CLI theme interface. Use git. Works well. Slate has versioning too, and so with your file watchers, branches, downloading and uploading... everyone will be in tune with their work, and you can keep a master -> Shopify thing going.